# Правильно ли расставлены знаки в предложении

Tags: запятые

А в библиотеке столько книг, что стоит только пожелать и окажешься в любом месте и любой временной эпохе...

Answer (score 2):

Лучше так:

*А в библиотеке столько книг, **что стоит только пожелать** —  **и окажешься** в любом месте и в любой временной эпохе...*

**Пояснение**

1. Выражение  ***стоит только*** (пожелать, захотеть и т.д.) здесь имеет значение обусловленности: ***нужно что-то сделать — и тогда....***

Это фразеологизованная конструкция  такого вида: ***СТОИТ (СТОИЛО) — И***.

2. **[Источник:](https://studfile.net/preview/3606533/page:53/)** § 3065. К фразеологизированным конструкциям со значением **обусловленности** относятся предложения, оформленные двухместными союзными соединениями стоит(стоило) — чтобы; **стоит(стоило) —как; стоит(стоило) — и;** достаточно—чтобы; достаточно—как; достаточно—и.

[https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словосочетанием/стоит+только](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82+%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE)

Comment: Как бы в моем ответе тот же вариант выбран, причем раньше.

Comment: Как бы да)) Но где вы здесь увидели придаточное?  Нужен не только правильный вариант, но и корректное объяснение.  А вы сразу об "авторстве" беспокоитесь. А зачем?))

Comment: Мы можем обособить это выражение для актуализации значения, но в этом нет особого смысла.

Comment: Придаточное? Оно, вообще-то, присоединяется союзом «что».

Comment: Ну тогда я не поняла ваше длинное объяснение.  Информативность стиля!  Попробуйте уложиться в два предложения)  Последователи этого стиля говорят: уважайте своего читателя.

Comment: У этого выражения есть условное значение, например:  Стоит только войти в осенний лес, и вы сразу окажетесь в другом мире. Оно может быть вариантом придаточного условия.  Если войти в осенний лес...

Comment: Тогда получается, к этому предложению применимы два варианта пунктуации? И с запятой, как вариант придаточного условия, и без запятой?

Comment: Какой нибудь знак (запятую или тире) надо поставить, но скорее всего тире. Дело в том, что здесь две предикативные основы, а перед второй основой стоит союз И. Структура частей разная, подчинительного союза нет, все это говорит в пользу тире. Посмотрите примеры из Карты слов. Там ставится запятая перед союзом ЧТОБЫ или КАК, если в предложении две основы. А в нашей схеме всего лишь союз И. Поэтому знак ставим обязательно, но лучше тире.

Answer (score 1):

*Я верю, стоит только пожелать,*

*И можно, вопреки всему земному,*

*Своей душой израненной взлетать,*

*Туда, где всё прекрасно по-иному!*

---

**Стоит только пожелать, и...** — вводное.

Но нам мешает союз *и* (**что** — вводная конструкция — **и**), нужны другие способы выделения вставки:

Возможны варианты:

*А в библиотеке столько книг, что, стоит только пожелать, — и окажешься в любом месте и любой временной эпохе...*

*А в библиотеке столько книг, что стоит только пожелать — и окажешься в любом месте и любой временной эпохе...*

[ПУНКТУАЦИЯ ПРИ ВВОДНЫХ СЛОВАХ И СОЧЕТАНИЯХ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2)

Answer (score 1):

***А в библиотеке столько книг, что стоит только пожелать — и окажешься в любом месте и любой временной эпохе...***

Тире перед союзом «и» указывает на последовательность действий (*пожелаешь — и окажешься*. *Пожелаешь, **потом** окажешься*), поэтому ставим его.

Если возникают сомнения по поводу запятой после *пожелать*, то я скажу — не нужна! Потому что «что стоит только пожелать — и окажешься в любом месте и любой временной эпохе...» — придаточная часть **целиком**, и никаких запятых, кроме запятой перед *что*, **не нужно!**

Фраза *стоит только пожелать* никак не может здесь являться вводной, потому что вводные слова всегда опускаются без потери структуры:

***А в библиотеке столько книг, что (стоит только пожелать) — и окажешься в любом месте и любой временной эпохе...***

Вам просто нужно убрать скобки — и вы поймете, что предложение как выглядит, так и слышится **неправильно**, то есть некорректно по структуре, поэтому ничего не нужно ставить.

---

Вывод: вариант пунктуации один — в начале ответа.